# Не включается enable Node js PHPStorm

Tags: node.js, phpstorm, jetbrains

[image: Скан]
Не включается кнопка в чем могут быть причины?

Comment: версия PHPstorm? предоставьте [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files), пожалуйста

Comment: @lena О_О саппорт JetBrains на SO.

Comment: @lena где его найти?!?!?!!!?!?!

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что его следует адресовать в соответствующую техподдержку

Comment: @Antonio112009, скорее всего, Ваша версия PHPstorm не поддерживает Node.js 8. Но без лога ничего конкретно сказать не могу. Найти его можно с помощью **Help | Show log in Explorer** (собственно, ссылка на соотв инструкции есть в моем комментарии выше)

Comment: @lena скинул idea посмотрите если не трудно https://drive.google.com/file/d/1psPjNq36-E-JyGUoqVwvNnjKfnp0onda/view?usp=sharing

Comment: спасибо! см. ответ:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы используете **PHPStorm 171.3780** - в нем нет поддержки Node 8. [WEB-26508](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-26508) была исправлена в 171.4636. Попробуйте обновиться до  **PhpStorm 2017.1.4** (https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Previous+PhpStorm+Releases), а лучше сразу до [2017.3](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/download)

Comment: Спасибо за оперативный ответ ! Помогли!)

Answer (score 0):

попробуй вместо `\nodejs\node.exe` (файла запуска) указать папку самого нода - `\nodejs`

В крайнем случае - скачай еще раз с сайта файл:

https://nodejs.org/en/download/